# javascript copy one array of objects to other but exclude few object elements while copying

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, javascript-objects

I have a below source array of objects

```
[
  {
    'joa Doe 1': 'Joe Doe 3',
    'joa1@doe.com': 'joe3@doe.com',
    __rowNum__: 2
  },
  {
    'joa Doe 1': 'Joe Doe 3',
    'joa1@doe.com': 'joe3@doe.com',
    __rowNum__: 2
  }
]
```

I want output something like below

```
[
  {
    'joa Doe 1': 'Joe Doe 3',
    'joa1@doe.com': 'joe3@doe.com'
  },
  {
    'joa Doe 1': 'Joe Doe 3',
    'joa1@doe.com': 'joe3@doe.com'
  }
]
```

Can someone please help me how to filter the array or copy to new one by excluding the rownum element form the object form array. I'm new to javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just using [**Array.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do it.

```js
let data = [
  {
    'joa Doe 1': 'Joe Doe 3',
    'joa1@doe.com': 'joe3@doe.com',
    __rowNum__: 2
  },
  {
    'joa Doe 1': 'Joe Doe 3',
    'joa1@doe.com': 'joe3@doe.com',
    __rowNum__: 2
  }
]

data = data.map(({__rowNum__,...rest}) => rest )
console.log(data)
```